# Place div at top screen relative to document

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an construction and I can't change a couple of elements.
The meaning is that the modal comes at the top, without changing the location of the div. (Or at least not above box3)

The elements I can change are box3, box4 and modal.

I want the yellow square to overlap over the whole document, now it is stuck in its parent (See snippet or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nebulosar/zgghmoLo/))
Is there any way to do this?

CSS & HTML:

```css
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box4 {
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
}

.box3 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  clear: both;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  height: 150px;
}

.box2 {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.upperRow {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20px;
}

.box1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<header>

</header>
<div class="box1">
  <section class="upperRow">

  </section>
  <section class="box2">
    <div class="box3">
      <!-- box3 CAN BE MODIFIED-->
      <div class="box4">
        <!-- box4 CAN BE MODIFIED-->

      </div>
      <div class="modal">
        <!-- modal CAN BE MODIFIED-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Comment: Can you post CSS, or a demo

Comment: on it, please hang on for css

Comment: I don't understand your question/problem, please clarify

Answer (score 1):

It's cause the parents have `position: relative;` or `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;`. If you remove that, it's  fine.

```css
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box4 {
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
}

.box3 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-right: 18px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  clear: both;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  height: 150px;
}

.box2 {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.upperRow {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20px;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<header>

</header>
<div class="box1">
  <section class="upperRow">

  </section>
  <section class="box2">
    <div class="box3">
      <!-- box3 CAN BE MODIFIED-->
      <div class="box4">
        <!-- box4 CAN BE MODIFIED-->

      </div>
      <div class="modal">
        <!-- modal CAN BE MODIFIED-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
<footer>

</footer>
```